# Where to find logs left by Find/Sed run from C program

Tags: c, linux

If a C program was used to send a combination of Find/Sed instructions to system, where would a system admin best find evidence of this happening, and is it possible to find the exact arguments passed to these programs? Just to say that I am mentioning that it is a C program doing this to exclude the bash history. Would really appreciate someone to give me a list of places to look.  Thank you.

pseudo code:
Way in which Find/Sed invoked:

```
Command= find .... exec Sed.....
sprintf(command,....
system(command);
```

Answer (score 1):

That would depend entirely on how the C program invoked find/sed, and whether or not it redirected the I/O.  There may not be any record of the process having been run unless some kind of [process accounting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/) is enabled.

Comment: Hi Jim, I have updated my post if that helps determine what could be checked. There is also one other variant on the find/sed command that uses grep, but it is echod to system in the same fashion as illustrated.

Comment: Also just to add that the find mechanism goes through all files starting at base dir (specified, lets say root for example), so would checking for left over sed temp files, or last file access times be any use?

Answer (score -1):

Either use absolute paths or use the function [getcwd](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getcwd) to get the current working directory and work it out from there where the files will be stored from the redirection.

Comment: How does this answer the question?